# Where is Asimov's "The Complete Stories" (Doubleday/Broadway) volume 3

Tags: short-stories, isaac-asimov, publishing

Doubleday started an ambitious project of collecting *all* of Asimov's short fiction between covers in 1990, with two volumes, containing 86 stories out of a total of 383. Broadway Books (New York) reissued those two volumes in 2001. My question is, ***what are the reasons why more volumes containing the rest of Asimov's Short Stories are not being published?*** Surely the publishers can't have lost faith in his unflagging popularity?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think a reason was made known, so we can only speculate. Perhaps the sales figures for the first two volumes were lower than expected and the publisher thought publishing further volumes would not be profitable.

Comment: "*This was probably a very bad idea, since it means that the pool of top-notch Asimov short sf is pretty much drained, **had Volume 3 been published, it would have contained mostly the dregs**.*" - www.asimovreviews.net